# Unban users if their nickname contains "x.."

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm not really sure how to make my bot unban everyone if their username contains xx, deleted.. etc.

For example, if a user's account got banned/deleted off discord, the bot will just unban them to clear the ban log, because it contains "Deleted User".

I'm providing my existing unban command which works based on IDs.

```js
/**
 * JSDOC
 * @param {Discord.Client} client
 * @param {Discord.Message} message
 * @param {String} args
 */
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.channel.send('You are not allowed to unban members!');
    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.channel.send('I am not allowed to unban members!');
    if (!args[0]) return message.reply('Please provide a user id to unban!', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
    const toUnBan = client.users.cache.get(args[0].match(/[1234567890]{18}/igm)[0]) || await client.users.fetch(args[0], true, true);
    if (!toUnBan) return message.reply('You didnt provide a valid user!', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
    try {
        (await message.guild.fetchBan(toUnBan));
    }
    catch (err) {
        return message.reply('The user isnt banned!', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
    }
    message.guild.members.unban(toUnBan);
```

Comment: If you use `\`\`\`lang-js` instead of `\`\`\`` when starting your code section, it will turn on syntax highlighting and greatly improve readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For unbanning users with a certain username, you need to fetch all the bans first, then filter them with the username, and then unban them.

```js
(await message.guild.bans.fetch())
.filter(ban => ban.username.toLowerCase().includes("deleted"))
.forEach(async(ban) => {
   await message.guild.bans.remove(ban.id).catch(e => console.log(e));
   console.log(`Unbanned ${ban.tag}`);
});
```

- Reference: [GuildBanManager#remove](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildBanManager?scrollTo=remove), [GuildBan](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildBan), [GuildBanManager#fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildBanManager?scrollTo=fetch) (*all of these are from discord.js documentation*)